# How to or where to add an image long description component?

Tags: image

How would you add a "long description" for an image in the content management interface? Where would the component (text?) be added. The open folder icon is defaulting to "Categories and Keywords."

Field:
Long description for complex graphics (describing the image in detail):

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange! The answer really depends on your company's setup. The fields you see as an editor are configurable and may vary based on the file (multimedia) or component type. Are you working with a team or a partner that can explain the fields?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your setup of content fields has a link to a separate Component to store the long description.

In either the Content Manager Explorer list view or in that item selector you will likely need to create the appropriate Component to then select from that Component link.

The command in the context menu would be right-click > New > Component.

[image: New > Component lets you create a new Component]

Each Tridion Sites setup will have their own content definitions (Schemas) and fields. You will have to check around your team, but the long description Component *might* be available from a Schema called "Long Description" or something like "article" or "content." But again, it really depends on your setup.

The list of Categories and Keywords in the item selector pop-up is there to let you browse items that have those tags (keywords), which is an optional way to select a Component.

However, you should be able to navigate the folders starting with Building Blocks > Content, though your specific folders may differ.

Note that a field for long description does not strictly need to be in a separate Component. Some content models (definitions, fields, and links) might put that description in either the Image Multimedia Component itself or in a Component linking to the Image. Talk to your content management or technical teams with questions specific to your setup.

Comment: OK, cool, thank you! Appreciate your time in responding. I was hoping this would be a quick direction to include a long description value and do understand technical teams would need to be involved.